# Using a Web Api 2 project to authenticate/authorize a separate client project's users

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api2

I'm having trouble getting the authentication portion working, particularly the external authentication. I'm using a client project to call my API, which then handles all the OAuth processing.

My issue is that once you authenticate through Facebook, it wants to redirect to my API url, and that redirect url has the `access_code` needed for authorization of subsequent API calls from the client. Is there a best practice for dealing with this situation? For instance, should I parse the `access_code` out of the url and somehow send it back to the client project?

Searching for how to handle this yields me vague results. Most everything I come across leads back to one of two links:

[This is helpful understanding the high level concept](http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/26/dissecting-the-web-api-individual-accounts-templatepart-3-external-accounts/)

[This implies that you should just dig around in the SPA template and figure it out on your own](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services#FQDN)

neither of which really help me out much in a "how-to" sense.

The client project I'm ultimately working with is a Xamarin project, so I'm looking for C# or Xamarin library code how-tos in particular. If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it.